# htaccess RewriteRule not executing properly

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to figure out why my Rewriterule doest work properly.

```
  RewriteRule ^en/(.*).php?(.*)#(.*) $1.php?$2&language=english#$3 [NC,L,QSA] 
  RewriteRule ^en/(.*).php?(.*) $1.php?$2&language=english [NC,L,QSA] 
  RewriteRule ^en/(.*).php#(.*) $1.php?language=english#$2 [NC,L,QSA] 
  RewriteRule ^en/(.*).php$ $1.php?language=english [NC,L,QSA] 
  RewriteRule ^en/$ index.php?language=english  [NC,L,QSA]
```

I can currently see english version by using `www.example.com/?language=english`

but when I'm tring to open `www.example.com/en` I see 404 page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)\.php $1.php?language=english [NC,L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.php?language=english  [NC,L,QSA]
```